# Apache Netbeans 10 IDE installation

Tags: apache, netbeans, installation, wizard

I just tried to install Apache Netbeans 10. It seems someone has introduced a lot of busiwork into the installation process.

In december 2018 I installed Netbeans 8 by

1. browsing to netbeans.org
2. clicking a button marked "download"
3. waiting for the wizard to install

In february 2019, trying to install Netbeans 10, I am instructed to:

1. fetch zipped files for netbeans
2. download and install apache ant
3. unzip netbeans
4. run ant on netbeans
5. and whatever else may follow.

Netbeans 8 is still available so obviously I did not waste my time on this new process.

Is this the future, or just a startup issue with Netbeans being transferred to Apache? 
How is the introduction of this manual labour progress?

I apologise if this question does not belong on stackoverflow. I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: [1] I answered a similar question to yours which was closed as being off topic: [How to install Netbeans 9 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305299/how-to-install-netbeans-9-on-windows). [2] Update your question if you still have any concerns after reading that. [3] There is no need to _"download and install apache ant"_. Can you provide the link which is telling you to do that? [4] All you need to do is download a zip file, unzip it to a local directory and then run NetBeans from the bin folder. I really don't see how the process could be any simpler.

Comment: 4. Thank you for clearing that up. Glad to hear it is that easy.

1. The other question was removed.

2. No concerns right now: Netbeans 8 is up and running. I will look into setting up netbeans 10 at a later date.

3. instructions on the Apache Netbeans site are: (https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html) 

Once you have everything installed then:
Unzip incubating-netbeans-10.0-source.zip in a directory of your liking.
cd to that directory, and then run ant to build the Apache NetBeans IDE. Once built you can run the IDE by typing ./nbbuild/netbeans/bin/netbeans

Comment: OK , cool - you should be able to have NetBeans 10.0 up and running a couple of minutes after downloading it. Also, note that you can safely install and run multiple versions of NetBeans concurrently. They won't impact each other at all as long as you don't open the same project in two instances at the same time, and you don't run servers from two NetBeans instances which are both trying to grab the same port.

Comment: The instructions are only valid if you want to compile NetBeans on your own. As skomisa already mentioned you just need to download the binaries-package, unzip and you are ready to go. Just remember that NetBeans 10 does not run on JDK8.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

For Linux system follow these simple steps (Apache Netbeans 10 per-requisites must be satisfied before going further):

1. Download script from [apache-netbeans-10.0](https://gist.github.com/Chetan07j/750e0dc2818a8e6316616f6900acfec3)
2. Open terminal in directory where above file is downloaded and run below command

   `sudo chmod +x ./Robo3T-Installation-Menu.sh`
3. Then type below command and hit enter

   `./apache-netbeans-10.0.sh`
4. Just wait to complete it, once completed enjoy Apache Netbeans. Search in menu with name "Netbeans".

Answer (score 0):

**Linux** alternative / no special scripts.

(Netbeans version 14. Might apply to 10, dunno)

Download and verify the installer file from [Apache Netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/)

Eg. `Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh`

Change the permissions to make it executable - 777'll do:

```
chmod 777 Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

then

```
Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh # launches GUI installer
Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh --help # lists options
Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh --silent # installs without gui
```

Your DE may then list it, if not try

```
/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-14/netbeans/bin/netbeans"
```

to launch

If not there try

```
find / -mount -name netbeans
```

to find it

(I got this with guessing and trial and error. There is zero useful documentation on the site - you could look inside the scripts I suppose.)

To add to DE (if not there):

create file `/usr/share/applications/Apache-NetBeans.desktop` ;

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Apache NetBeans IDE 14
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code 
Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-14/netbeans/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-14/netbeans/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

**3 Months later ...**

Still on Netbeans 14 and all ok in Alma Linux 8.5 (RHEL Clone) but then upgrade to 8.6 and Netbeans stops working - won't launch. Others having similar issues on macOS and fingers pointing at openjdk 17:

```
17.0.3.0.6-2.el8_5  working
17.0.4.1.1-2.el8_6  not working
```

but don't want to downgrade as who knows what that'll break and can't dnf install both at same time so installed Oracle JDK 17 (java version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-18 LTS ), used "alternative --config java" to set it as default and Netbeans working again.